# WSO2 ESB as a JMS Producer and Consumer

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have been trying to do a poc and WSO2 ESB as a JMS producer and consumer. First thing a could not understand is that how our proxy service will consume the message, do we need to initiate or run the service using tryit or soap ui, or it will consume message every time whenever there is a new message in the queue.

can anyone suggest a link or provide a step by step example for this.

below are my proxy service source:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="NewJMSQueue" transports="jms" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>               
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>               
         <default>application/xml</default>           
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">NewJMSQueue</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the required libraries to ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib folder (activemq-core-5.7.0.jar, geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, and geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar)

Comment: i have copied geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar,
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1,jar
hawtbuf-1.9.jar,
activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar,
activemq-client-5.8.0.jar,
activemq-all-5.8.0) files to repository/components/lib folder.

Comment: one more concern, whenever i am creating jms transport based service i am getting following error: Unable to configure the service JMStoHTTPStockQuote for the VFS transport: Service doesn't have configuration information for transport vfs. This service is being marked as faulty and will not be available over the VFS transport.

Comment: What is the transport you have configured for this proxy. Looks like you have configured "vfs" transport for the proxy. Please re-visit the config.

Comment: I was getting this exception because i have added extra jar file. when i removed activemq-all-5.8.0.jar it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can find several examples from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/JMS+Usecases) where ESB is used as a JMS consumer and a producer.

When you put the message into the queue the proxy will automatically pick it from the queue. That is by default ESB will be listening on a JMS queue with the same name as the proxy service and when there is a message proxy service will pick that. Note that you have to [configure](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+Samples+Setup#ESBSamplesSetup-SettinguptheJMSListener) the JMS transport listener in order achieve that.

Comment: I have uncommented  the JMS transport listener for ActiveMQ and sender in ESB_HOME\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml file. and i have created a queue in named "NewJMSQueue" in ActiveMQ, and created the proxy with the same name as you can see in my above proxy source code. but still i am not able to consume message from the ActiveMQ Queue.

Comment: @vashishth Can you see that there is any Message consumers for the ActiveMQ queue? you can use the ActiveMQ Web console fot that.